# Why fminsearch doesn't estimate parameters?

Tags: matlab, function, parameters, fminsearch

I'm trying to estimate the parameters of the following function:

u = log(x) - ω - φ*(log(h)) - δ1*z - δ2*(z^2-1)

I'm using the function fminsearch in matlab with the following codes:

```
data = xlsread('return_oc_out.xlsx');
a = data(:,25);

kernel = xlsread('RK_out.xlsx');
rkAA= kernel(:,25);

startingVals = [0.1 0.05 0.9 0.3];
T = size(a,1);

options = optimset('fminsearch');
options.Display = 'iter';
estimates = fminsearch(@residuiRK, startingVals, options, rkAA, h, a);
[ll, lls, u]=residuiRK(estimates, rkAA, h, a);
```

the function residuiRK has the following code:

```
function [ll, lls, u] = residuiRK(parameters, x_rk, h, data)
omega = parameters(1);
phi = parameters(2);
delta1 = parameters(3);
delta2 = parameters(4);

mu = mean(data);
T = size(data,1);
eps = data-mu;
z= eps./sqrt(exp(h));

lxRK=log(x_rk);
u = zeros(T,1);
for t = 1:T 
u(t) = lxRK(t) - omega - phi*h(t) - delta1*z(t) - delta2*(z(t).^2-1);
end 
lls = 0.5*(log(2*pi) + log(exp(h))+eps.^2./exp(h));
ll = sum(lls);
```

The problem is: the fminsearch returns the estimated parameters equal to the starting values that I insert. Why there is this problem? 
I will be very grateful if someone could explain it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call your function like

```
[estimates, ~, exitflag, output] = fminsearch(...)
```

to diagnose your function call. `exitflag` should be 1 if the tolerance was reached, otherwise something wrong happened. `output` is a structure that you can consult to see the run summary of your `fminsearch()` call.

<s>Also, your function call seems weird. You want to optimize over the `parameters` argument of `residuiRK` function, right? Then, why not passing the rest of arguments to your `fminsearch` minimized function? Like this:</s>

```
estimates = fminsearch(@(x) residuiRK(x,rkAA,h,a), startingVals, options);
```

**Later edit**

So, based on the new info, apparently the `exitflag` of `fminsearch()` call is 1. Which means that the maximum coordinate difference between current best point and other points in simplex is less than or equal to `options.TolX`, and corresponding difference in function values is less than or equal to `options.TolFun`.

Your function might vary too slowly around `startingVal`. You could try to increase/decrease your tolerances. This can be done by modifying the `options` struct:

```
options = optimset('fminsearch');
options.Display = 'iter';
options.TolX = <some number>   % the default value is 0.0001
options.TolFun = <some number> % the default value is 0.0001
```

Try different values an see what happens to your values. If nothing happens, then apparently you guessed the minimum's position from the start. :-)

Comment: CST-link I had diagnose the fminsearch with exitflag and it results to be 1. I want to estimate the parameters of the function ResiduiRK and then, put into the function ResiduiRK the estimated parameters to have the residuals of the function. I tried with your last code but it doesn't work

Comment: @user3553802 It doesn't work as in "it throws an error" or it doesn't work as in "it gives the same parameters back"?

Comment: CST-link it gives this error : Error in ==> fminsearch at 205
fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});

Comment: @user3553802 Modified my answer with some more suggestions.

Comment: I tried to modify with your suggestions but I still have the same problem.. The estimates are always the same of the starting values :(

Comment: Any values I impose in option.TolX and option.TolFun don't change the estimates and the message is that the x satisfies the termination criteria and the F(x) satisfies the convergence criteria. Maybe the problem is another..

Comment: @user3553802 Sorry. Without some data with which I can see how `residuiRK` works, I'm afraid my "guessing game" is not a very good one. :-)